# Scrollbar cuts images

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
   <style type="text/css">
    div {display:inline-block; height:200px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;}
        a {display:block;}
    img {border:0;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you see the right part of images are cut. I know I can estimate the scrollbar width and give a fixed width to the `div`, but I wonder if there's a better approach.

Comment: [**JSfiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gNF2z/)

Answer (score 0):

as there are no reset css that why its may problem

but you can try this to add an css attributes on div

```
div{padding-right: 25px;}
```

its may output as better